# Where is ruby stored on mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, macruby

I am looking for a path of where ruby gets stored on mac?

I installed macruby on my mac and I am trying to see where it got installed. I want to include the path of macruby in my ruby script. When I do rvm list, I get:

```
=> macruby-0.12 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-1.9.3-p545 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.2-version [ x86_64 ]
```

I use `#!/usr/local/bin/macruby` in my ruby script, but looks like macruby is not present in that location. When I execute "whereis ruby" command on I get back `"/usr/bin/ruby"`, but when I execute `"whereis ruby-1.9.3-p545"` or `"whereis macruby-0.12"` I get nothing.

How do I find the path of where does all these ruby versions lie?

Comment: There is a neat command you can do in your Terminal. `gem env`. It will show you `RUBY EXECUTABLE` along with a lot of more useful locations.

Comment: you can do `which ruby`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get the path to the local executable with

```
$ which ruby
```

the rvm rubies are in your rvm directory, which I believe is `~/.rvm/rubies` (I use rbenv so not sure about the details)

The which command should pickup whatever shims/other magic RVM is using to set your shell ruby

Comment: Hmmm I use homebrew. Looks like it's same for rbenv and homebrew too. I found it under the same path. Thanks John!!

Comment: what if somebody isn't using rvm? then `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 6):

You can find your answer by running one of the following commands:

```
 which ruby
 whereis ruby 
 type -P ruby
```

Comment: that will only tell somebody if they already have ruby installed

Comment: `which ruby` and `type -P ruby` >> `/Users/me/.rubies/ruby-2.6.2/bin/ruby` give the location of the currently activated Ruby, at least on my High Sierra macOS using chruby. `whereis ruby` >> `/usr/bin/ruby` gives the location of the system Ruby. My testing conditions were `chruby ruby-2.6.2`.